# do while loop ignores my bool flag variable c++

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, do-while

If userList[i].CheckUser(username, password) returns false then it enters the else condition and I get the output "User Does Not Exist! Try Again Enter username and password" that line then gets stuck in an infinite loop and I cant figure out why, I mean the program re-enters the do-while loop again so I don't see how the loop would carry over?

```
int main()
{   
    LoadUsersFromDatabase();
    bool flag;
    string username;
    int password;
do{
    cout << "Enter username and password: ";
    cin >> username >> password;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfUsers; i++)
        if (userList[i].CheckUser(username, password) == true)
        {
            if (userList[i].GetUserType() == 'A')
            {
                ProcessAssistantMenu();
            }
            else if (userList[i].GetUserType() == 'M')
            {
                ProcessManagerMenu();
            }
        }
        else
                cout << "\rUser Does Not Exist! Try Again! ";
                flag = false;
  } while(flag == false);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uninitialized local variables will have an *indeterminate* value. Using an uninitialized local variable will lead to *undefined behavior* in C++. Fortunately you are lucky that your `flag` variable never *is* uninitialized, since you always and unconditionally set it to `false`.

Comment: @mch: I just rolled back your edit - the poor formatting (and lack of braces) is actually part of the problem with the user's code here, so fixing it obscures the solution.

Comment: @Dean: please don't fix your code on-the-fly - it invalidates existing answers and will be confusing for future readers.

Comment: sorry ill change it back, the problem is I have added the braces and set the flag variable to true and still have the same error

Comment: Another thing I just noticed: Where do you set `numOfUsers`?

Comment: its a global, I know globals are bad but  necessary for this particular program

Answer (score 4):

You are always setting your `flag = false`.

I'm guessing you want to do this:

```
else{
    cout << "\rUser Does Not Exist! Try Again! ";
    flag = false;
}
```

And as Alex points out, you're not setting it `true` in the first place.

Comment: yes because if the return is true on .checkUser and it enters the ProcessAssistantMenu()  or  ProcessManagerMenu()  both have an exit(1) within the function, so its just poor programming and convention on my part however it has been rectified by initializing the flag to true, yet fixing the braces and initializing the flag did not seem to solve my problem, i don't know where the infinite loop is coming from

Answer (score 2):

The flag is never set `true` in the loop.

Comment: More importantly, it is never set to `true` *in the loop!*